# Django auth form jump to login page

Tags: python, django, authentication

I would like to protect some web pages to let only authenticated users have access, and if the user is not authenticated, then jump him to the login page. But I have some errors, because authenticated users jump to a dead link.

Here's the code.

Entry page :

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def add_entry(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = entryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            note = form.save(commit=False)
            note.save()
    else:
        form = entryForm()
    return render(request, 'add_entry.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^add-entry/$', views.add_entry, name='add_entry'),
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'auth/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
```

Dead link:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/add-entry/login/?next=/add-entry/
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: `login_url` should be the URL of your login view, `login/` will redirect relative to the URL being requested. What do you want to redirect to?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington to login page,i don't have login view in my views.py.

Comment: Well you can't redirect to a login view if you don't have one? Where do you want users to be redirected to?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington for my main page like `127.0.0.1:8000/` work fine don't work only if I have url like this  `r'^add-entry/`

Comment: What's the URL of your login page?...

Comment: @Iain Shelvington `url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'auth/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm})` final `127.0.0.1:8000/login/`

Comment: Then your decorator is wrong, `login_url` should be `/login/`

Comment: @Iain Shelvington yes look to work now thank you very much